# Stack exchange log-in fail

Tags: support, login

I know this is not the place to ask this but I'm desperate I've just signed up to the stack exchange about an hour ago but it won't let me on because no email has gone though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callum, I'm not sure what you mean as here you are, 'in'!!
In the FAQ it says this "Do I have to log in or create an account?.You can ask questions, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like Wikipedia. There are some things you won’t be able to do on the site without registering, such as vote. But it’s easy to register". So just carry on with your questions, someone will help you here. We want to encourage more people to join the great Ubuntu community!!

Comment: Thank you alot you are very helpful I hope more people are like you.